# R "caret" package running into compile environment error

Tags: r, r-caret

I have tried searching for an answer and absolutely can't seem to find any solution to this. I have recently installed the "caret" package for R, but when I try to train any models at all, it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: namespace ‘compiler’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘sep’
Error in comp(expr, env = envir, options = list(suppressUndefined = TRUE)) : 
  could not find function "makeCenv"
```

From what I can tell, this has to do with the built-in compiler package. Most of the answers I have seen mention the doMC package, but I don't think this is relevant here because I'm not parallelizing anything. I have been able to run the same code successfully on other machines, so I'm completely stumped as to what the problem might be. Here's some sample code that causes the error for me:

```
library(caret)
fit.knn <- train(Species ~ ., data=iris, method="knn")
```

It doesn't seem to matter what method I use, or what data I train on. I have tried reinstalling the package, and reinstalling R as well. I'm running R v.3.3.2 on Windows, and the caret package is the most recent version. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution to this issue. I had been using an idiosyncratic setup where I had set my library location to a global folder so I wouldn't have to move all my packages from the "3.2" folder to the "3.3" folder, etc. every time I updated R. My solution worked, but had the side effect of removing the default library location in Program Files (the one that includes the base packages).

That seemed to work completely fine for everything I did, so I never noticed an issue until I started using *caret*. But for some reason, apparently the built-in *compiler* package (used by some dependency of *caret*) doesn't work properly with that setup, and needs an explicit reference to the Program Files library location in `.libPaths()`. After changing things back to the default, everything seems to work fine.

So although this is an obscure error and probably not something people are likely to experience, for those arriving here from Google, check `libPaths()` and make sure there are two locations there: your user folder (in "My Documents" by default) and the default library location that includes all the base packages (in "Program Files").

Comment: I had the same problem with Caret package and could solve it by updating Rstudio and installing the version of Caret which is one version older than the most recent one.